# Consultas mais elaboradas em MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
Responsavel:
id       | responsavel_email
1        | joão@joao.com
2        | pedro@pedro.com
3        | maria@maria.com
4        | luiza@luiza.com

Aluno:
id       | nome_aluno      |classe_id
1        | Marli           | 1
2        | Joel            | 2
3        | Alonso          | 2

relacionamento:
    id       | Aluno_id        |responsavel1_id |responsavel2_id
    1        | 1               | 1              | 3
    2        | 2               | 2              | 4
```

Precisava fazer um SQL em que eu eu falasse quero emails dos pais da Casse 2 o sql respondesse

```
relacionamento:
        id       | Aluno_id        |responsavel1_id |responsavel2_id
        1        | Joel            | pedro@pedro.com|luiza@luiza.com
```

Cheguei a essa consulta ..

```
    SELECT
   responsavel.nome_responsavel,
   relacionamento.responsavel1
FROM
   responsavel
INNER JOIN
   relacionamento ON responsavel.id = relacionamento.responsavel1
```

porem agora preciso do WHERE

Comment: Gabriel, coloque o código que você esta tentando fazer para que possamos ajudar, do modo que você postou você esta pedindo para que faça para você e não que te ajudem...

Comment: Eu não tenho noção de como fazer, eu sei fazer consultas simples , eu tentei fazer usando este exemplo Select * tabela inner join tabela2 WHERE campo = 0 and campo2 = '' and campo3 or campo10 is NULL

Fiz as substituições para as minhas e mesmo assim não obtive o resultado

Comment: Eu consegui chegar a essa consulta em q ele me da um geral, agora precisava tentar fazer um WHERE com a Classe do aluno

SELECT
   responsavel.email,
  relacionamento.responsavel1
FROM
   responsavel
INNER JOIN
   relacionamento ON responsavel.id = relacionamento.responsavel1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta esse script:

```
SELECT A.id, A.nome_aluno, RES1.responsavel_email, RES2.responsavel_email
FROM aluno A
INNER JOIN relacionamento R ON R.Aluno_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN responsavel RES1 ON RES1.id = R.responsavel1_id
LEFT JOIN responsavel RES2 ON RES2.id = R.responsavel2_id
WHERE A.classe_id = [ID da classe]
```

Comment: Realmente essa ajudou, eu estava com dificuldade de conseguir fazer o próximo Join , até um eu conseguia ...Valeu mano !